# show first 3 thumbnails of posts in different sizes

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails, query-posts, get-posts, images

i want to make a little Header with the 3 recent thumbnails in different sizes
and start my loop with the 4th recent posts, can someone give me a function for that please? please no widgets i want to make it raw and get more into webdesign.

U can see how it looks on my page: http://web91.s67.goserver.host/

the 3 grey boxes should contain the thumbnails of the 3 recent posts and the the loop underneath should start then with the 4th post (2 different thumbnail sizes)

I already know how to define the sizes in the functions which looks like this right now:

```
// Add featured image support
add_theme_support(‘post-thumbnails’);
add_image_size(‘small-thumbnail’, 600, 330, true);
add_image_size(‘big-thumbnail’, 600, 661, array(‘left’, ‘center’));
```

but i have no idea how to implement the thumbnails in the right sizes into the 3 grey boxes and how to start with the 4th post underneath

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the loop, you can access the current loop item's index by using the `current_post` method. You didn't post any code, so I'm just going for a simple demonstration.

```
If ( have_posts() ) {
    while( have_posts() ){
        the_post();

        // Setting the global $wp_query to access the method
        global $wp_query;

        // Get the current post's index
        $current_post = $wp_query->current_post;

        // Let's calculate the thumbnail size based on the current post's index
        switch ( $current_post ) {
            case 1 :
                $size = 'size-1';
                break;
            case 2 :
                $size = 'size-2';
                break;
            default :
                $size = 'post-thumbnail';
                break;
        }

        // Now we have the proper thumbnail size
        the_post_thumbnail ( $size );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code. It's an updated version of the code posted by @Jack Johansson.

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $thumbnail_size = 'size-after-3-posts';

    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        // Get the current post's index
        $current_post = $wp_query->current_post;

        // Post index starts from 0 (zero)
        // 1st post will have big-thumbnail and 2nd & 3rd will have small-thumbnail
        if ( 0 === $current_post ) {
            $thumbnail_size = 'big-thumbnail';
        } elseif ( 1 === $current_post || 2 === $current_post ) {
            $thumbnail_size = 'small-thumbnail';
        }

        // Now we have the proper thumbnail size
        the_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail_size );
    }
}
```